# Solving the system $\sin\theta\,(A+\cos\phi)=\cos\theta\,(B+\sin\phi)$, $\sin\phi\,(C+\cos\theta)=\cos\phi\,(D+\sin\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Is there an easy way to solve the following system of trigonometric equations (that is, to find $\theta$ and $\phi$)? A,B,C, and D are known constants.

$$\sin\theta\,(A+\cos\phi)=\cos\theta\,(B+\sin\phi)$$
$$\sin\phi\,(C+\cos\theta)=\cos\phi\,(D+\sin\theta)$$

All I can think of is to derive $\tan\theta$ in terms of $\phi$ from the first equation, and then plug it into the second equation, but then I'd come up with a complicated equation (although with only one variable). So I am wondering if there is a simpler method to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also getting a complicated equation (a polynomial of degree six). Is there reason to believe there should be a "nice" answer? Is there some relation among $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ that you haven't mentioned? ... It might help if you told how the system arose. Is it a textbook exercise? an online challenge? something of your own?

Comment: This is actually the simplified form of another system of equations that I encountered when trying to model a wireless network. A, B, C, and D are functions of (many of) the system parameters but there is no simple relation between them.

Comment: Is this $$\sin(\theta(A+cos(\phi))$$ etc?

Comment: No, it's sin$(\theta)$ .($A$+cos$(\phi))$

Answer (score 1):

One partial answer (really a comment too long for the comment box) in the more general case where $A^2 + B^2 \neq C^2 + D^2$. The system can be recast as
\begin{align*}
\sin \theta \cos \phi - \cos \theta \sin \phi &= B \cos \theta - A \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta \cos \phi - \cos \theta \sin \phi &= C \sin \phi - D \cos \phi
\end{align*}
The LHS of both equations is $\sin (\theta - \phi)$, and each RHS can be rewritten with the help of phasor diagrams as
\begin{align*}
-A \sin \theta + B \cos \theta &= \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} \sin \left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan \frac{A}{B}\right) \\
C \sin \phi - D \cos \phi &= \sqrt{C^2 + D^2} \sin\left(\phi - \arctan \frac{C}{D}\right)
\end{align*}
and equating these quantities may least may simplify the task of finding a solution numerically, but I doubt an analytic solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I started with an assumption of $ A^2+B^2=C^2+D^2$. Here's what I came up with,
$\sin\theta(A+\cos\phi)= \cos\theta(B+\sin\phi) \Rightarrow A\sin\theta-B\cos\theta=-\sin(\theta-\phi) \ldots  (1)$

Similarly $C\sin\phi-D\cos\phi = \sin(\theta-\phi) \ldots (2)$.

$\therefore (1)$ & $(2)$ together give $A\sin\theta-B\cos\theta= D\cos\phi-C\sin\phi$ $ \Rightarrow \sin(\theta-\theta_1)=\sin(\phi_1-\phi) \ldots (3)$, where both $\theta_1$ and $\phi_1 $ are known because $A,B,C,D$ are known, namely $\tan\theta_1=\frac{B}{A}$ and $\tan\phi_1=\frac{D}{C}$.

Now the solution of equation $(3)$ gives $\theta-\theta_1=\phi_1-\phi$ (Discarding any general solution). It implies $\theta= \phi_1+\theta_1-\phi \ldots (4)$

Substituting the value of $\theta$ in $(2)$ gives  $\sin(\phi-\phi_1)=\sin(\phi_1+\theta_1-2\phi) \Rightarrow \phi=\frac{1}{3}(2\phi_1+\theta_1).$ Value of $\theta$ can be found from $(4)$. Here I did not consider any general solution because ranges of $\theta$ and $\phi$ are not specified.

Answer (score 0):

I find it numerically easier to solve this equivalent pairs:

$$\sin(\theta-\phi) = -A \sin(\theta) + B \cos(\theta)$$
$$\sin(\theta-\phi) = C \sin(\phi) - D \sin(\phi) $$

If A,B are constants, convert (-A,B) to [angle notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_notation), $r_\theta ∠ γ_\theta $
If C,D are constants, do the same: (C,-D) → $r_\phi ∠ γ_\phi $

Let $x=\theta-\phi, \text{we have } \sin(x) =  r_\theta \sin(\theta + γ_\theta) = r_\phi \sin(\phi + γ_\phi)$

$$\theta = \sin^{-1}({ \sin(x) \over r_\theta}) - γ_\theta   $$
$$\phi = \sin^{-1}({ \sin(x) \over r_\phi}) - γ_\phi   $$
You can guess the gap of angles, x, solve for the 2 angles, and try the new gap.

Example, say A=1, B=4, C=7, D=8

x $= +0.0000, \text{ we get } \theta≈-1.8158, \phi≈0.8520$
x $ = -2.6678, \text{ we get } \theta≈-1.9267, \phi≈0.8090$
x $= -2.7357, \text{ we get } \theta≈-1.9117, \phi≈0.8148$
x $= -2.7265, \text{ we get } \theta≈-1.9137, \phi≈0.8140$
x $= -2.7277, \text{ we get } \theta≈-1.9135, \phi≈0.8141$
x $= -2.7276, \text{ we get } \theta≈-1.9135, \phi≈0.8141$

---

We can speed up convergence with Newton's method:
$$f(x)= \theta-\phi-x= \{\sin^{-1}({ \sin(x) \over r_\theta}) - γ_\theta\} - \{ \sin^{-1}({ \sin(x) \over r_\phi}) - γ_\phi \} - x $$
$$f'(x)=\large \cos(x) \left({1 \over \sqrt{r_\theta^2-\sin(x)^2}} - {1 \over \sqrt{r_\phi^2-\sin(x)^2}}\right) -1 $$

For the same example, iterate with $x = x - \large{f(x) \over f'(x)}$:

+0.0
-3.13285623900302
-2.72899493772358
-2.72760870383572
-2.72760865698240 $ → (\theta,\phi) = (-1.91349280095738, 0.81411585602502)$

Comment: is there a reason that these steps would converge to the solution? I mean, does it have any advantage over random guessing?

Comment: Can you show what you meant by random guessing ?

Comment: I mean just trying different values of $\theta$ and $\phi$ over and over again until the both equations hold. Does your method provide a faster way to solve the equations?

Comment: Fixed point iterations for the angles, convergence is not very fast.  For my example, about 1 decimal digits gain per iteration.  I tried Newton's method (added to my answer), convergence is much faster.

Comment: I don't know why but, using your numbers, I don't get the same numerical result.

Comment: For (A,B,C,D)=(1,4,7,8), there are multiple solutions.  Limiting angles inside ± pi, this is what I found so far: (θ,ϕ) = (-1.9135, 0.8141), (-1.6611, -2.3494), (1.2411, 0.8848).

Comment: @albertchan. You are very correct and I am ... stupid ! Cheers :-(

Comment: Can you provide an iterative numerical solution if the second main equation was replaced by $sin\phi (C+cos\theta)= -cos\phi (D+sin\theta)$?

Comment: Why not use @ClaudeLeibovici f(ϕ), but flip the sign before D?

Comment: (A,B,C,D)=(1,4,7,8), angles within ± pi, I think there are 4 solutions. (θ,ϕ) = (-1.9135, 0.8141), (-1.6611, -2.3494), (1.2411, 0.8848), (1.4534, -2.2403)

Comment: Does the iterative numerical method guarantee to find all the solutions (say, within ±pi)?

Comment: Since f(x) = θ - ϕ - x, and  (θ,ϕ) involve asin, to get full solutions, you had 2*2 = 4 f's to solve, thus 4 solutions. My answer only do the principle asin angle.  But, try θ = (pi - asin(sin(x)/r(θ))) - γ(θ), and solve f(x)=0, you would get @ClaudeLeibovici solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you initial idea is worth to use.

From the first equation
$$\theta=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{B+\sin (\phi )}{A+\cos (\phi )}\right)$$ which means that we look for the zero of
$$f(\phi)=\left(C+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2(\phi)+1}}\right) \sin (\phi
   )-\left(D+\frac{x(\phi)}{\sqrt{x^2(\phi)+1}}\right) \cos (\phi )$$ where $x(\phi)=\frac{B+\sin (\phi )}{A+\cos (\phi )}$

Using $A=1$, $B=4$, $C=7$, $D=8$ as albert chan did and using Newton method, the iterates are 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \phi_n \\
 0 & 0.00000000 \\
 1 & 1.20154495 \\
 2 & 0.87333496 \\
 3 & 0.88478716 \\
 4 & 0.88478758 
\end{array}
\right)$$ from which $\theta=1.24111220$.

As I wrote in comments, I do not know why our solutions are different.

For sure, the analytical expression of $f'(\phi)$ would be quite messy but using central differences will not make any problem.